# Related Rates: Conical Pile

Tags: calculus, derivatives

At a sand and gravel plant, sand is falling off a conveyor, and onto a conical pile at a rate of 10 cubic feet per minute.  The diameter of the base of the cone is approximately three times the altitude.  At what rate is the height of the pile changing when the pile is 15 feet high?

### My Attempt

Given:

> $\frac{dV}{dt}=10 \frac{\mathbb{ft}^3}{\mathbb{min}}$
> $d=3h \therefore r=\frac{3}{2}h$
> $h=15$

Unknown:

> $\frac{dh}{dt}=?$

Equation:

> $V=\frac{h}{3}\pi (\frac{3}{2}h)^2$
> $V=\frac{3}{4}h^3\pi$

Then from here I would take the derivative, and solve for $\frac{dh}{dt}$ right?  For an answer I got .0068, which I think is wrong.

Comment: Any reason why you think it's wrong?  That's what I got.

Comment: I thought it would be bigger, since its the change in height. I honestly thought it would be bigger.

Comment: Think of it this way... when the height is 15ft, the volume is nearly 8000 cubic ft.  An extra 10 cubic feet isn't going to be such a huge addition to such a large pile.

Comment: But when the pile is 15 feet high, the height won't really be changing very quickly.

Comment: Since the volume at $h=15$ is nearly $8000$, an extra $10$ cubic feet is only a $1/8\%$ change in volume. And since an increase in height from $h$ to $h+\Delta h$ causes an increase in volume from $\text{constant}\times h^3$ to $\text{constant}\times (h+\Delta h)^3$, the percentage increase in height should be only about $1/3$ the percentage increase in volume, so about $1/24\%$. And $1/24\%$ of $15$ is ... $0.00625$. That's close enough to your answer; there are multiple approximations in the calculations in this comment, so we can hardly expect exact agreement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $V = \pi r^2 \frac{h}{3}$
2. diameter $= 3h \Rightarrow r = \frac{3}{2}h$
3. $V(h) = \pi \cdot \frac{9}{4}h^2 \cdot \frac{h}{3}= \frac{3}{4}\pi h^3$
4. Height is a function of time since the height increases as sand piles on.
5. I.e $V(h) = (V \circ h)(t)$
6. Let $t_0$ be such that $h(t_0) = 15$. You just need to solve:

$$10=\frac{d}{dt}\Bigr|_{t = t_0} ( V \circ h)(t) = V'(h(t_0)) \cdot h'(t_0) $$